# Getting all BLE services from Android app

Tags: kotlin, go, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android app, that must connect to a BLE server, discover its services, and read a specific characteristic of a specific service.

The server code is written in go and is [a simple template that I took here](https://github.com/go-ble/ble/blob/master/examples/basic/server/main.go). From it, I register a service and a characteristic with the followings UUIDs:

```
MyService:         00010000-0001-1000-8000-00805F9B34FC
MyCharacteristic:  00010000-0002-1000-8000-00805F9B34FC
```

Then here's  my Android code that discovers for services:

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                gatt?.services?.forEach { service ->
                    Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "new service: ${service.uuid.toString()}")
                    if (service.uuid == EnrollServiceUUID) {
                        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "SUCCESS")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Error while fetching services: $status")
            }
        }
```

if I scan for my go server with an nRF connect app, here's what I get:

[image]

(Notice that my declared service is found with the declared UUID)

But when running my android code: Here are the services I find:

```
onServicesDiscovered: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
onServicesDiscovered: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
onServicesDiscovered: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Actually I figured out that my service and my characteristic have been "renamed" to another UUIDs. In fact, only the two first parts are modified, as following:

```
Go server     | Android app
00010000-0001 | 180a-0000
00010000-0002 | 00002a50-0000
```

I'm able to interact with from my app, but I would like to understand why they have a different UUID that the ones I declare from my Go server and I see with nRF connect.

Comment: Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to test your server implementation. If your services do not appear there your go server is at fault

Comment: Where is your custom service in nRF connect? I see 0x1801 and 0x1800, both of which show up in your `onServicesDiscovered` output. (I don't see 0x180a, Device Information, in the nRF output, though.) What output do you expect from onServicesDiscovered?

Comment: When I register a service from my go server, I use a pseudo-random UUID. I expect to see it here. By the way the nRF output I provided is not the interesting one. Let me update it

Comment: Your nRF screenshot shows exactly the same information as your `onServicesDiscovered` output (and almost the same information as you previous text output). What output do you expect from `onServicesDiscovered` that you're not seeing (I mean the literal string you're expecting; don't describe it. What's the actual number that you see in the nRF output and not Android?)

Comment: You are right, and this is already a good start. The issue is that I register my services / characteristics with some UUID, and those are not the displayed ones, I don't understand why

Comment: So it sounds like your actual question is on your server side, not Android. I would start with the example server "as-is" with no changes of your own, and make sure that works with nRF Connect. If that works, then you've injected a bug in your Go code, and you can work from there. If it doesn't, then either the example you're copying is buggy, or you're misunderstanding something about it.

Comment: I updated the post to make the question clearer